# Parsing XML file stored in internal storage using DOM parser in android.

Tags: android, xml, dom, xml-parsing, domparser

I have created an xml file in the device's internal storage as described on the android developers website. I now want to parse the file using DOM parser. What do i need to do to make the DOM parser read my XML file??
Here's a snippet:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dom = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(data)));
    dom.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

What do i need to put in the place of "data" in:

```
    Document dom = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(data)));
```

I know it's silly but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a input stream of the xml string like below and then getting nodes you can parse to get values.

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(theXMLString.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        // Build XML document
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

Remember you are passing xml file as a string.

Comment: *"Remember you are passing xml file as a string."* ... how do you do that? How do you go from a `File` object to an `InputStream`?

Answer (score 1):

You can give FileInputStream in inputsource

Document dom = db.parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(data)));

Comment: and give the filename in place of data?

Comment: No you need to get an inputstream from the file as like:File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

Comment: its not working. I created the file in internal storage and read it back in the String variable "data". when i display the contents of data it gives me the file output. But When i pass "data" in db.parse(...), I dont get an error but somehow i dont get any parse results either. Further code:    dom.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        Element root = (Element) dom.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList items = ((Document)root).getElementsByTagName("network");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "node length: "+ items.getLength(), 
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: I dont know why are you reading a file by outputstream, we can read a resource by input stream, and InputSource requires a input stream, reader in paremeter, please check carefully, if your file writing code get executed successfully, problem might be there.

Answer (score 1):

For reading XML file, you should try below

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/text.txt");
StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);

BufferedReader inRd = new BufferedReader(isr);

String text;
while ((text = inRd.readLine()) != null) {
    inLine.append(text);
    inLine.append("\n");
}
in.close();

String finalData =data.toString();  // Here is your data.
```

Hope above may useful to you.

Comment: i'm getting the file contents back exactly as they are. But my problem is how to make the DOM parser read the file or the inputStream data??

Comment: Now you can use
 Document dom = db.parse(finalData);

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for parsing from Asset folder using DOM Parser :

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory DBF;
    DocumentBuilder DB;
    Document dom;
    Element elt;

    DBF = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DB = DBF.newDocumentBuilder();
    dom = DB.parse(new InputSource(getAssets().open("city.xml")));
    elt = dom.getDocumentElement(); 
    NodeList items = elt.getElementsByTagName("item");
```

where item is Node element, add try ctch block as per the requirements.